# Changing user's current directory in a PHP cli script

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu

In a PHP cli script I'm writing I need to change the path for the *user* that's running the script. The destination path is not fixed.

The script will be used on machines running on Ubuntu. With a bash script I could use sourcing, but that doesn't seem to work with PHP scripts. When I try that, the hashbang referring to the php binary at the top of the script is ignored and the script interpreted as a bash script. I don't really know what else to try.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: http://php.net/chdir

Comment: @Farkie I don't think that's relevant here - you cannot use `chdir` (or any other function for that matter) to modify the parent shell.

Comment: Oh, you can't modify the parent shell.. You could technically spawn another bash shell whilst inside php after changing dir..
chdir('..');
pnctl_exec('/bin/bash');

Comment: You can't directly modify the parent's current directory from a child process.  Would it be possible to wrap the child PHP process ... for example, have the PHP script generate a sourceable bash file?

Comment: @Beel Hmm, as in make a bash script that runs the PHP script, which in turn writes a sourceable file at a predestined location, and when it returns the original bash script sources it? I think you may have just found a solution. :)

Comment: @Schlaus, yep, that's the idea.  Wasn't sure if your use case would allow such an approach.  Sorry I don't know PHP well enough to provide a complete answer.

Comment: @Beel that's ok, the code itself isn't a problem. Since your idea solves the problem, please make it an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the problem, you have a parent process that will launch PHP in a child process to execute a PHP script.  And you want the logic of that PHP script to cause the parent process' working directory to change.  The PHP script cannot directly modify the parent's working directory.  But ... you can have the child PHP script create a new file that contains a `cd newpath` command, then `source` that newly created file.  So

Some `main.sh` script file contains something like:

```
/bin/php /path/to/the/php/script.php
source /tmp/generatedscript
rm /tmp/generatedscript
```

`script.php` should create a new tmp file that contains only a `cd` command with the desired directory as target.  `main.sh` can `source` that file, and you are now in a new wd.

Be sure to `source` the `main.sh` so that the commands all run within the current process.

Comment: If you were going to do that you might as well use `eval` instead of a tempfile — `eval \`php whatever.php\``